# Blazor WASM custom elements in razor pages only working on the root (Index.cshtml) page

Tags: c#, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly, hosted-blazor-webassembly

I modified this Blazor Custom Elements Sample (".NET 7 Blazor Custom Elements Sample hosted in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages": https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/BlazorCustomElementsSample) to show the problem. I also updated the project to the current .NET 7, and also removed the no longer needed `<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements/BlazorCustomElements.js"></script>`

The problem can be verified when you run the updated project, where I added the custom element to other pages: https://github.com/horacioj/BlazorCustomElementsSample

When you add a custom element to **/privacy** or **/some/routed/page**, the custom element `<my-counter title="Khalid" increment-amount="2" />` does not work.

In the **/privacy** page, the problem is: `GET https://localhost:7213/Privacy/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements.lib.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

In the **/some/routed/page** page, the problem is: `blazor.webassembly.js: GET https://localhost:7213/some/routed/_framework/blazor.boot.json 404`

I have no clue about how this could be solved.

Reference: **Blazor custom elements**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-custom-elements

Thank you

EDIT:
It worth noting that when removing `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements" Version="7.0.1" />` from `BlazorSolo.Components.csproj`, the old way to instance a Blazor component (`<component type="typeof(Counter)" param-title="@("the title")" param-IncrementAmount="3" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />`) works fine on any page.

If the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements` package is kept, the `<component...>` fails too, with the same errors in the JS console, even after removing any reference to `builder.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<Counter>("my-counter");` and `<my-counter title="routed page" increment-amount="2" />`

Could this be a bug in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45818

https://github.com/mkArtakMSFT says:

> you're missing a line in your index to register the base path for the app. That is, adding `<base href="/" />` to the head section of the Layout.cshtml file.